# Transferring data from website to google docs

Tags: sql, python-3.x

So I want to transfer information from a returned order from our website and I want to click a button and transfer some of that orders information (date it was received, order #, part#, quantity of # being returned.). 
What's the fastest way to do this? 
As of right now we are doing google docs spreadsheet to keep track of what is being returned and I am writing down every return manually.

Can we create a script or program that runs everytime this task is performed? It doesn’t seem like a big task but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this API https://developers.google.com/sheets/ This allows for manipulation of data in the Google Excel sheets.